# What is the way to store a 2-D array pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have a 2-D array of floats:

```
float a[1024][1024];
```

I want to store the pointer to array

I did:

```
float** temp = a;
```

but doesn't seem to work. It gives the error:

> main.cpp: In function `'int main()'`:
> main.cpp:105:24: error: cannot convert `'float (*)[1024]'` to `'float**'` in initialization
>
> ```
>    float ** temp = old_array;
> ```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Since this is tagged C++ I would suggest you use `std::array<std::array<float, 1024>, 1024> a; auto& b = a;` Assuming you have a C++11 compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays decay to pointers. In the case of 2D arrays, an array of type `T[x][y]` will decay into `T(*)[y]`, not to `T**`.

> **§ (8.3.4) Arrays:**
>
> If `E` is an n-dimensional array of rank `i × j × ... × k`,
>   then `E` appearing in an expression that is subject to the array-to-pointer conversion (4.2) is converted to a
>   pointer to an `(n−1)`-dimensional array with rank `j × ... × k`. If the `*` operator, either explicitly or implicitly as a result of subscripting, is applied to this pointer, the result is the pointed-to `(n − 1)`-dimensional array, which itself is immediately converted into a pointer.

Your options are to manually reconfigure the type to match the type of the expression...

```
float (*temp)[1024] = a;
```

or use a multi-deminsional `std::vector` or `std::array` (C++11)...

```
std::array<std::array<int, 1024>, 1024> a;
auto temp = a;
```